# Distance function: $d(x,x)$ must equal zero?

Tags: prime-numbers, metric-spaces

Let $p$ be prime and assume $\lVert r\rVert_{p}=p^{-k}$, if $r=p^k(m/n)$, where $m$ and $n$ are relative primes of $p$. Define $$d(x,y)=\lVert x-y\rVert_{p}$$ on $\mathbb{Q}$. Show that $d(x,y)$ is a distance function on $\mathbb{Q}$.

---

I started to try to show this but it seems to me that, for $d$ to be a distance function on $\mathbb{Q}$, we need $d(x,x)=0$. However, I can't see how $d$ can ever be zero, since $p^{-k}$ can't be zero.

Or have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Isn't it defined as $0$ for $r=0$? (cf. http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:P-adic_Norm)

Comment: Thanks Kuba, that has saved me a lot of head scratching!. The definition of $\lvert\lvert 0\rvert\rvert_{p}=0$ wasn't given in my problem, and I didn't know that it was a standard norm. I am sure that the definition was just left out of the question accidentally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be closed:

$d(x,x)=0$ by definition.